# Python - Django, Cannot install mysqlclient using pip

Tags: python, django, pip, django-mysql

I'm new to Django and I'm facing some issues installing mysqlclient for my application running this command

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I'm getting an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.operations.build.wheel_legacy'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\Python-projects\web_project\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "e:\python-projects\web_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "e:\python-projects\web_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "e:\python-projects\web_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pip._internal.wheel_builder import build, should_build_for_install_command
  File "e:\python-projects\web_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel_builder.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.build.wheel_legacy import build_wheel_legacy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.operations.build.wheel_legacy'
```

I have ***Python 3.8.3*** and ***pip 20.2.3***

what is the cause of this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: If you switch to 64-bit Python on Windows, then `pip install mysqlclient` will be able to install the official wheel.

Comment: thank you, I switched to 64-bit Python and it worked like charm